# PDF reporting options from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, autohotkey

I've recently started creating a small application for the company I currently work at to assist with their financial side. They used to do a lot of manual excel work for this in the past.

Most of the work is done in SQL Server 2016 (Enterprise) and a lot of the actions are controlled by stored procedures. For the interface I've created a simple gui app using Auto Hotkey as this is the language I'm still most familiar with outside SQL.

What options, preferably free, can I look at to generate my reports from the sql data? (The reports are mostly invoices etc. that will be created from parameters)

I'm used to working with Crystal reports at my old job.
I've already created a basic report using SQL Report Builder which works fine, but I don't know how to directly run the report with parameters. (From a stored procedure or windows command).

Comment: SQL Server offers Reporting Services. The report builder is only the tool that allows you to build reports, not the report service itself. SSRS offers a [SOAP service endpoint and direct URL access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-into-applications?view=sql-server-2016) to the reports.

Comment: The article [Export a Report Using URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-2016) shows how to create a URL that returns a report in the format you want. The very first example exports to PDF. The URL is `https://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=PDF`

Comment: _I don't know how to directly run the report with parameters. (From a stored procedure or windows command)._ SSRS gives you an excellent web portal that lets users view and run your reports. (It also lets you upload excel into it and display KPI's and stuff). If you don't want to use the portal, what tool do you propose that the end users use? As mentioned in other comments, you can put a URL into a browser and have it prompt the users for parameters directly